# Hostfile not working for subdomain

Tags: network, dns, hosts

I'm trying to setup custom A records for domains via /etc/hosts on my OSX 10.13.2 MBP.

It usually works just fine, first time that it works only for 1 of the 2 domains:

- 1.2.3.4 dev.com (works; points to 1.2.3.4)
- 1.2.3.4 admin.dev.com (doesn't work; points to live IP 5.6.7.8)

I tried flushing DNS cache as well without success using:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Pinging both domains returns 100% packet loss

```
PING dev.com (1.2.3.4): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
```

Also tried different browsers (Opera, Firefox, Safari) as I know Chrome is pretty agressive with DNS caching.

Any idea?

EDIT: IP adresses and domains are pure fiction here.

Comment: Try using: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Comment: It depends on whether 1.2.3.4 is a placeholder in your question only. The real addresses 1.2.3.4 (or 1.1.1.1) are [defunct/filtered](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/feb/5/ripe-plays-with-1-0-0-0-network-apnic-allocation/) because a lot of people use it as placeholders. `ping sld.tld` (1.2.3.4) really times out!

Comment: @user3439894; seems like killing the process worked it's magic! 
@klanomath; indeed, it was just for the example :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @user3439894 comment to the original question, directly killing mDNSResponder processes fixed the issue for me.

Command used was:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

From the [killall manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) page:

> killall sends a signal to all processes running any of the specified commands. If no signal name is specified, SIGTERM is sent.
>
> Signals can be specified either by name (e.g. -HUP or -SIGHUP ) or by number (e.g. -1) or by option -s.